# Filtering through csv's in sub-directories with criteria

Tags: python, csv, os.walk

Currently, I have this code which finds all the "*_results.csv" files and copies these files to a new directory:

```
import os.path
import shutil

base_dir = r'\temp'
dest_dir = r'\temp1'

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(base_dir):
    for filename in [f for f in files if f.endswith("_results.csv")]:
        shutil.copy2((os.path.join(root, filename)), dest_dir)
```

All of these csv files have two columns, but the number of rows varies. All of the csv files have two rows in column A that say "Power" and "Speed", with the values for Power and Speed in column B. It is important to note that "Power" and "Speed" are sometimes in different row numbers within Column A depending on the csv.

For example --

```
x       x
x       x
Power   -20
x       x
Speed   35
```

I am looking to find all the csv's that have a Power >= -18 or where the Speed - Power >= 5.

Any help would be very appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: first you have to open and read data to check `Power`, `Speed` but it seems you didn't event try to read it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for each file, you can do:

```
df = pd.read_csv("file.csv")
powerdf = df[df.A == "Power"]
thepower = powerdf.iloc[0][B]
if thepower >= -18:
   return True
speeddf = ...
```

And so on.

Comment: So simple. Thanks for the help.